# Running out of YouTube quota what are my options?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-php-client

I am working customer relationship department and creating an app which is replying to every YouTube comment.

So what i am making right now is basically a script which pull comment data from YouTube Data API v3. This script is a looping script which is being called every 30 seconds, however you may know the YouTube API has a quota limit and I keep hitting it.

I am open for any solution:

- Do I have to apply for more quota to YouTube
- How much quota should i apply ( basically im only pulling comment data, from who, id , and timestamp ) or sis there any other way.

## my code

```
<?php



if (!file_exists(__DIR__ . '/youtube_vendor/autoload.php')) {

  throw new Exception(sprintf('Please run "composer require google/apiclient:~2.0" in "%s"', __DIR__));

}

require_once __DIR__ . '/youtube_vendor/autoload.php';

include "mysql.php";

$db  = new db();

$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setAuthConfig('client_secret.json');

$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly');

$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl');



$client->setRedirectUri('your_url');

// offline access will give you both an access and refresh token so that

// your app can refresh the access token without user interaction.

$client->setAccessType('offline');

// Using "consent" ensures that your application always receives a refresh token.

// If you are not using offline access, you can omit this.

$client->setPrompt("consent");

$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth

$auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();

if(isset($_GET['code'])) {

    // id index exists

    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);

    $access_token = $client->getAccessToken();

    // var_dump($access_token);

    // echo "<br><br>";

    // file_put_contents("received.txt",var_dump($access_token));



    //     $access_token = file_get_contents("received.txt");

    //     // $file = json_decode($fb);

    // var_dump($access_token);

    // serialize your input array (say $array)

$serializedData = serialize($access_token);



// save serialized data in a text file

file_put_contents('youtube_access_token.txt', $serializedData);



// at a later point, you can convert it back to array like:

$recoveredData = file_get_contents('youtube_access_token.txt');



// unserializing to get actual array

$access_token = unserialize($recoveredData);



// you can print your array like

print_r($access_token);

    echo "<br>";

    $client->setAccessToken($access_token);

    $service = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

    // $channel = $youtube->channels->listChannels('snippet', array('mine' => $mine));

    // var_dump($channel);

$queryParams = [

    'maxResults' => 25,

    'mine' => true

];

$arrayComment = array();

$arrayReplies = array();

$responseVideo = $service->activities->listActivities('snippet,contentDetails', $queryParams);

foreach($responseVideo['items'] as $video)

{

    $db->insert_youtube_video($video['snippet']['channelId'],$video['snippet']['channelTitle'],$video['snippet']['publishedAt'],$video['snippet']['title'],$video['snippet']['description'],$video['snippet']['thumbnails']['standard']['url'],$video['contentDetails']['upload']['videoId']);



    $queryParams = [

    'videoId' => $video['contentDetails']['upload']['videoId']

    ];



    $responseComment = $service->commentThreads->listCommentThreads('snippet,replies', $queryParams);

    foreach($responseComment['items'] as $comment)

    {

        $db->insert_youtube_comment($comment['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['authorChannelUrl'],$comment['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['authorDisplayName'],$comment['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['authorProfileImageUrl'],$comment['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['publishedAt'],$comment['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['updatedAt'],$comment['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textDisplay'],$comment['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['videoId'],$comment['snippet']['topLevelComment']['id']);

        $queryParams = [

            'parentId' => $comment['snippet']['topLevelComment']['id']

        ];



        $responseReplies = $service->comments->listComments('snippet', $queryParams);

        foreach ($responseReplies['items'] as $replies)

        {

            $db->insert_youtube_replies($replies['snippet']['authorChannelUrl'],$replies['snippet']['authorDisplayName'],$replies['snippet']['authorProfileImageUrl'],$replies['snippet']['publishedAt'],$replies['snippet']['updatedAt'],$replies['snippet']['textDisplay'],$replies['snippet']['videoId'],$comment['snippet']['topLevelComment']['id'],$replies['id']);            

        }

        $arrayReplies[] = $responseReplies;

    }

    $arrayComment[] = $responseComment;

}







}

else

{

    echo $auth_url;

}



?>

<textarea style="width:100%;height:300px"><?php print_r($responseVideo['items']); ?><?php print_r($arrayComment); ?><?php print_r($arrayReplies); ?></textarea>
<script>
setTimeout(function () { window.location.reload(); }, 15*1000);
document.write(new Date());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I have to apply for more quota to YouTube

if you want to avoid hitting the quota and continue to make the number of requests you are making now. Yes you need to apply for a quota extension.

I would apply as soon as possible it can take a long time to get an extension.

> How much quota should i apply ( basically im only pulling comment data, from who, id , and timestamp ) or sis there any other way.

That is up to you.  How many requests are you making every day. You will need to do some math then pad it to ensure for future in crease of your application.